Can exception. __traceback__ be None for an exception caught in try-except?
Submitting this code (BTW, it prints None):
try:
    1/0
except Exception as err:
    print(err.__traceback__.tb_next)

to mypy produces an error:
# error: Item "None" of "TracebackType | None" has no attribute "tb_next"  [union-attr]

Can this happen? A caught exception with a traceback equal to None?

That's what typeshed says: https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/72623c6b151db070817ce4b1c1ad70a6a2007197/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L1822. I don't think in practice a caught exception would ever have no traceback, but it's certainly possible for an exception instance to be created without one (Exception().__traceback__ is None, for example).

@jonrsharpe Some exception objects could have null traceback, but can a caught exception have a null traceback? In other words - should the code be fixed or should the mypy be silenced at that line?

@VPfB Good point. mypy should be made aware of a caught exception indeed IMHO. Best to raise this issue with mypy's devs.

Let's take a closer look at this code.
You have a try-except statement here to catch any errors (exceptions) that might occur between "try:" and "except".
When the line with "1/0" is executed, it causes a ZeroDivisionError, as that operation cannot give a finite answer.
Your try-except statement catches this error and copies the result to your variable, err.
err.__traceback__ gives you details of the Exception, i.e.:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 1, in <module>

1/0


ZeroDivisionError: division by zero <- err.__traceback__ refers to this

err.traceback.tb_next looks to find any more layers of an exception (you have only one layer, whereas if the code was in a module, another layer, if it was in a module in a class, another and so on.)
In your experience, MyPy produces an error despite most IDEs in which .tb_next finds the next layer of an exception. This is most likely not a problem on your side, but in the way MyPy is written. Check your version, as this may be the reason.

You are not answering the question.
